# What is the average year_max - year_min in these sql tables?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables: actors, movies and cast:

```
mysql> desc actors;

+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id        | int          | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| full_name | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| gender    | varchar(1)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> desc movies;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int          | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| title | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| year  | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| genre | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

and

```
mysql> desc cast;
+----------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| actor_id | int  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| movie_id | int  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| salary   | int  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The connection between tables is: `cast.movie_id = movies.id and actors.id = cast.actor_id`

The question: what is the average career longevity(years between the first film and the last film) of
actors who were at least in five films during their career?

I have tried to list actors ordered by the number of films, they took part in:

```
mysql> select full_name, count(title) as movie_title from cast, actors, movies
    -> where cast.movie_id = movies.id and actors.id = cast.actor_id
    -> group by full_name
    -> order by movie_title
    -> desc limit 2;

+--------------------------+-------------+
| full_name                | movie_title |
+--------------------------+-------------+
| Kevin Bacon              |           9 |
| Bill Paxton              |           3 |
```

...
If what I've done is correct (not sure), we have only one such actor, so the question will be how to find this span

Will be very grateful for any advice!

Comment: `MAX(year) - MIN(year)` will tell you the career longevity

Comment: You should learn to use ANSI JOIN instead of cross-products.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: tried this:  mysql> select full_name, max(year) - min(year) as dis, count(title) as movie_title from cast, actors, movies
    -> where cast.movie_id = movies.id and actors.id = cast.actor_id
    -> group by full_name
    -> order by movie_title
    -> desc limit 2;

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow and congratulations on posting your first question. In future you are likely to find that people will respond more quickly and less aggressively if you can manage to make your questions a little shorter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT AVG(YearsActive) TotalAverage
FROM (
-- by actor
         SELECT a.id                        AS ActorId,
--      GROUP_CONCAT(a.full_name) AS ActorName,
                (MAX(m.year) - MIN(m.year)) AS YearsActive
         FROM actors a
                  INNER JOIN cast c ON a.id = c.actor_id
                  INNER JOIN movies m ON c.movie_id = m.id
         GROUP BY a.id
         HAVING COUNT(0) >= 5
     ) B
;
```